# Next.js static and dynamic metadata not working

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I'm checking this [document](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata) to add either static or dynamic metadata to my page. When I run the page in localhost I can't see the metadata in the head. If I add it directly using `<meta>` everything works as intended.

The sample code when trying to use it directly in `index.js` is:

```
import Layout from "@/components/layout"

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>This is an example</div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Another issue I noticed is that if I tried to add the metadata in the `layout.js` file then I get the following error even though I'm not using the "use client" directive.

```
You are attempting to export "metadata" from a component marked with "use client",
which is disallowed. Either remove the export, or the "use client" directive. Read
more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive
```

This is the `layout.js` code:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
}

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is a layout</p>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The doc also mentions the following:

```
Config-based Metadata: Export a static metadata object or a dynamic generateMetadata
function in a layout.js or page.js file.
```

What constitutes a layout file? Is it any file called `layout.js`? Is it dependant on its parent directory same as pages?

You can find a sample of the project [here](https://github.com/darincon/metadata-issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample repository you've provided is running Next.js 14 and is using the Page router methodology. Ideally, you should be using the App router methodology and I think this is where your problems are coming in. If I recall correctly, the Page router methodology components are client by default and you're attempting to use App router (server side components by default) functionality.

In the App router, there are special files to be used and in this case they would be:

- `layout.tsx` - the page at this level and its descendants will automatically use this layout.
- `page.tsx` - uses the layout from `layout.tsx` at the same level. You don't need to import and use the component defined in `layout.tsx`.

Here's an example structure, in TypeScript, of the App router:

```
- app
  - layout.tsx
  - page.tsx
  - child-1
     - layout.tsx
     - page.tsx
  - child-2
     - page.tsx
```

- `/` (`app/page.tsx`) - will show the content of `page.tsx` inside `layout.tsx`.
- `/child-1` (`app/child-1/page.tsx`) - will show the content of `page.tsx` inside the `layout.tsx` at the same level and all of that will be nested inside the `app/layout.tsx`.
- `/child-2` (`app/child-2/page.tsx`) - will show the content of `page.tsx` inside the `app/layout.tsx`.

This is quite an oversimplified answer and there's a lot more to read in the App router documentation. The tl;dr of it is you need to use the App router instead of the Pages router for metadata functionality you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I just noticed that the documentation I found is specifically for using App Router

Comment: FWIW, in my case, I had added a `<head>` tag in the root `layout.tsx` that was not letting the metadata in the individual `page.tsx` files, update the title. This answer helped me figure that out.

Comment: Helped me out a lot, thank you! Moving to the app router solved my metadata woes.

Answer (score -1):

The `metaddata` object will not be automatically injected into the `<head>` of your document when using Next.js. You will have to use `Head` component from `next/head`. So, `metadata` object has to be manually used in `Head` component to set the title and description.

Try this way...

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Layout from '@/components/layout';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <meta name='description' content={metadata.description} />
      </Head>
      <div>This is an example</div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

The other error clearly mentions that you're trying to export `metadata` from a component that is using, or is nested within a component using, the `use client` directive. But your `layout.js` does not seem to use that.  the error might be originating from a parent component or from a misunderstanding of the project structure.

layout.js is not a special type of file recognized by the framework itself. It is the common pattern used to create a constant structure across multiple pages. It is the typical React component which wraps around the main content of the page. Like you can use consistent header, footers and other elements you want.

Comment: This is likely the case when using the Page router, but the OP is running Next.js 14 and attempting to use functionality intended for the App router.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using static or dynamic metadata. Check the examples in the documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata).
The problem might be what Jason mentioned. Not using App Router.